# MYSQL output into existing HTML template

Tags: html, mysql, bash, redeclare

How can I output result into existing html template, using MySQL & Bash.

If I Write:

```
mysql --host="${VARS[6]}" --database="${VARS[9]}" --user="${VARS[7]}" \
      --password="${VARS[8]}" --execute="SELECT 1 FROM table_name" \
      --html --skip-column-names > $FILE
```

I get the result

```
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TR><TD>1</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

I want to get

```
<TABLE><TR><TR><TD>1</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

How can I re-declare a template so that MySQL is the output?

Comment: If you are set on doing this via BASH you could output from MySQL as XML and use XSLT to format it.

Comment: I know, what I can use XML. But I want output from MySQL to HTML.

Comment: XSLT can output whatever you want. HTML included.

Comment: I know about XSLT but for my task I need work with HTML-file like XML-file. But this attribute BORDER=1 makes error in xml validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "--xml" option to MySQL and then transform the resulting XML output into either HTML or some other form of XML with XSLT.

Otherwise, if you don't need to retrieve data containing whitespace from MySQL, you can parse "mysql -ss" output and generate HTML in Bash.

Like this:

```
mysql -ss your_mysql_option... |
    while read col1 col2 col3; do
        echo "
            <TR>
                <TD>$col1</TD>
                <TD>$col2</TD>
                <TD>$col3</TD>
            </TR>
        "
    done
```

Comment: This is one way to parse result.